# find common columns of two files and print first file values on 3rd file

Tags: unix

I have two large files like;

File1

```
0.678 JA0678
0.567 JA0907
0.345 JA0408
```

File2

```
0.574 JA0907
0.467 JA2345
0.347 JA0678
```

I want the output like;

```
0.678 JA0678
0.567 JA0907
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1}NR!=FNR && $2 in a{print a[$2], $2}' file1 file2
0.567 JA0907
0.678 JA0678
```

Comment: @user2240691 voting buttons are here for you to express your gratitude

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if($2 in seen) print seen[$2] " " $2; else seen[$2]=$1}' File1 File2
```

Output:

```
0.567 JA0907
0.678 JA0678
```